# Separate 2 arrays in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

My data `df`(shape `921 x 1`) looks like this:

```
0   ([0.0, 1.000198452073824, 2.000396904147648, 3.0005953562214724, 4.000793808295296], [52.91299603174603, 2.780002186077006, 2.428444682099035, 1.9729659176640224, 1.5245086521901212])
1   ([0.0, 1.000198452073824, 2.000396904147648, 3.0005953562214724, 4.000793808295296], [57.50430555555556, 4.605307698264335, 2.7257004204330895, 1.111884516011248, 2.0447376735106446])
2   ([0.0, 1.000198452073824, 2.000396904147648, 3.0005953562214724, 4.000793808295296], [52.05765873015873, 1.990137471526215, 1.823401414136555, 1.6393595029653947, 1.4975752877718798])
3   ([0.0, 1.000198452073824, 2.000396904147648, 3.0005953562214724, 4.000793808295296], [53.68928571428572, 0.5887958646369542, 2.4033544090769765, 1.2524139261039222, 1.6913320792004485])
4   ([0.0, 1.000198452073824, 2.000396904147648, 3.0005953562214724, 4.000793808295296], [52.049007936507934, 1.1250301372221871, 1.2300821162657336, 1.2122777908972708, 1.0745457469170827])
...
```

Checking individual row data, it outputs the following:

Code:

```
test = df.iloc[920,0]
test
```

Output:

```
(array([0.        , 1.00019845, 2.0003969 , 3.00059536, 4.00079381]),
 array([59.32333333,  4.57267936,  1.4308551 ,  2.68190521,  1.87502486]))
```

My question is how to separate the 2 arrays in each row in df. As I want to apply further functions to the second array. Thanks

---

Update:

Here's what it looks like after applying `Option1`:
[image]

I am not sure what went wrong. It does not seem to have split the 2 arrays, and the remaining rows showed `NaN`.

Comment: i don't understand what you want, you want to separate the result of iloc?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Hi in short yes. But I want to do it for all rows in `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

There's `pandas.DataFrame.explode`, but this will create new rows when splitting the collection instead of column.

In your case, where you want new columns, you can explicitly create another column for this analysis from the second element of the row.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'test': (([1,2,3], [4,5,6]),)})                                                                                                                                                         

In [3]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[3]: 
                     test
0  ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])


In [4]: df['test_2'] = df.test.apply(lambda x: x[1])                                                                                                                                                               

In [5]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[5]: 
                     test     test_2
0  ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  [4, 5, 6]
```

If you want to extract the first column you can also add

```
df['test_1'] = df.test.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Finally, to only have the split-ed column.

```
In [7]: df.drop('test', axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: 
      test_2     test_1
0  [4, 5, 6]  [1, 2, 3]
```

With this, applying further function is easy.

```
df.test_2.apply(some_function)
```

**Option 2**

Or, you do not actually need to split it in the first place! Here's what you can do:

```
def some_function(row):
    data_to_transform = row[1] # use second column in row
    ...
    return transformed_data

df['transformed_data'] = df.test.apply(some_function)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer Darren. But Option1 seems only applies to the first row. Can we improve on that? Cheers

Comment: @nilsinelabore What do you mean by only applies to the first row? My sample data only has 1 row so that's it, but it should be working for dataframe with multiple rows..

Comment: Hey Darren please see the edited question for update. Thank you

Comment: @nilsinelabore As written in my answer to split, please use `df.COL_NAME.apply(lambda x: x[0])`, not `df.apply(lambda x: x[0])` because this needs to be applied in each row for that column. In my case my `COL_NAME` is `'test'`, hence it's `df.test.apply()`.

Comment: @nilsinelabore Hey, does this help?

Comment: Hi, I tried this:`df['test_2'] = df.iloc[:,1].apply(lambda x: x[1])

df['test_1'] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: x[0]) 

df.drop('test', axis=1)`and received `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. Since I don't have the column name, I used index instead. Is this the reason why? Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. You can use the column index if doesn't have the column name, i.e. `df[<column_index>]`, it's actually the same with using iloc, but simpler. For instance, `df['test_2'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x[1])`. It's always be index `0` since you only have one column, that's why doing `df.iloc[:,1]` in your case produces index out-of-bounds.

Comment: Hi Darren, thank you so much for the follow up. It worked out the second time but I incurred some other issue during another trial probably because of my own problem. I will try to fix the other issue later on. But I really appreciate your help. Cheers.